# Find $\iint_S 4 dA$ where $S$ is boundary of $x^2+y^2\le 9, \quad 4\le z\le 11$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I am asked to find
$$\iint_S 4    dA$$

Where $S$ is the boundary of $x^2+y^2\le 9, \quad 4\le z\le 11$

Not sure on how to start working on this integral, any guidance on how to start, which theorems to use and how to think this integrals would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: Look at your surface and choose a ''nice'' coodinate. The express dA in that coordinate.

Comment: Split it into 3 surfaces and find a parameterization for each surface.